# Relationship between Ruby on Rails' application gemfile and the engine's gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

I recently inherited a Rails project that is 2 years old, running on Rails 3.0.x.
Given that all the referenced gems are pretty old, I wanted to upgrade them (as most of them have a couple of bug fixes by now). The application built on top of an engine in the vendor/plugins.

I am new to RoR and I want to better understand the relationship between gems referenced in the application's gemfile and those in the engine's gemfile. I would say about 80% of the referenced gems are the same. Their versions are different thought.

What are the implications of having the same gem but with different versions? Are both being loaded?

Should I strive to keep them in sync or is this a very common use case?